# bulding docker image for several script

Tags: python, docker

I have 2 python script and one R script but the main scripts to run are the python script (I call the R script in one of the python scripts). I have to `dockerize` all these script. to do so I have made `Dockerfile` which is here:

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /opt/app/
ADD ./ ./

RUN pip3.7 install -r ./requirements.txt

CMD python3.7 qc.py
CMD python3.7 cano.py
```

So, I have 2 questions:
1- shall I include the R script in the `Dockerfile`? (that is `myscript.r`)

2- before running the docker image I need to build the image. if I had one script (`qc.py`) to run I will use the following command to build image:

```
sudo docker build -t qc .
```

but what would be the command to build the image for the `Dockerfile` with more than one script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docker image produced when calling `docker build` should stay separate from the *execution* of the scripts.

To execute something that's inside of an image, you can use `docker run`.

*Using your example:*

This is the directory with your `Dockerfile` in it:

```sh
$ tree .
├── Dockerfile
├── cano.py
├── myscript.r
├── qc.py
└── requirements.txt

0 directories, 5 files
```

We want to build a docker image that has all of the R and Python scripts in it, and all of the dependencies to *execute* those scripts, but we don't necessarily want to run them yet.

In your `Dockerfile`, you don't have the dependencies needed to run `myscript.r` because the base image (`FROM python:3.7`) doesn't have the required packages installed. I looked up what was required to run an R script in the **r-base** [repo on docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/r-base/) and in [the repo on github](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker), and then added it to the `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM python:3.7

# Install the dependencies for R
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y r-base r-base-dev r-recommended

# Add all of the scripts to the /opt/app/ path inside of the image
ADD . /opt/app/

# Change the working directory inside of the image to /opt/app/
WORKDIR /opt/app/

# Install the python dependencies in /opt/app/requirements.txt using pip
RUN pip3.7 install -r ./requirements.txt

# This command just shows info about the contents of the image. It doesn't run any
# scripts, since that will be done _AFTER_ the image is built.
CMD pwd && ls -AlhF ./
```

Notice that the default `CMD` doesn't run any of the scripts. Instead we can do that using the `docker run` command from the terminal:

```sh
# The --rm removes the container after executing, and the -it makes the container interactive
$ docker run --rm -it qc python cano.py
Hello world! (from cano.py)
```

Now, putting it all together:

```sh
# Starting in the directory with your Dockerfile in it
$ ls .
Dockerfile  cano.py  myscript.r  qc.py  requirements.txt

# Build the docker image, and tag it as "qc"
$ docker build -t qc .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  6.656kB
Step 1/6 : FROM python:3.7
 ---> fbf9f709ca9f
Step 2/6 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y r-base r-base-dev r-recommended
# ...lots of output...
Successfully tagged qc:latest

# Run the scripts
$ docker run --rm -it qc python cano.py
Hello world! (from cano.py)
$ docker run --rm -it qc python qc.py
Hello world! (from qc.py)
$ docker run --rm -it qc Rscript myscript.r
[1] "Hello world! (from myscript.r)"
```

I've collected all of the example code [in this github gist](https://gist.github.com/blackrobot/c313ed427c8995df5de3b3b1993632f4) to make it easier to see everything in one place.